# Laravel Route: Multiple Route Group With Prefix and Route Model Binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Hello wonderful people of SO!

I have a problem about Laravel Route which I cannot solve.

In User.php model I use getRouteKeyName() function

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```

And also in Post.php model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'uuid';
}
```

In users table, 1 have one record

```
|----------------------------|
| id | ... | user_name | ... |
| 1  |-----|  @simple  |-----|
```

In posts table

```
|------------------------------------|
| id | ... | uuid              | ... |
| 1  |-----| abcd-123-efg-456  |-----|
```

In route (web.php)

```
// for post (key: uuid)
Route::group(['prefix' => '{post}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

// for users (key: user_name)
Route::group(['prefix' => '{user}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});
```

Then let say we visit url: **[www.example.test/@simple/](http://www.example.test/@simple/)**

In debugbar, I see query:

> select * from `posts` where `uuid` = '@simple' limit 1

**What I have tried**

> [#1] I put where clause in route groups for posts and users

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{post}',
    'where' => [
        'post' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}$' // I'm not Regex professional
    ]
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{user}',
    'where' => [
        'user' => '^(@)[a-zA-Z0-9]$' // I'm not Regex professional
    ]
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});
```

So let's try again visit the url: **[www.example.test/@simple](http://www.example.test/@simple)**

What i got, 404

> [#2] I deleted the getRouteKeyname in both User and post model

revisit url: **[www.example.test/@simple](http://www.example.test/@simple)**, still got 404

> [#3] I tried to put Route Model Binding Column Name

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{post:uuid}', // This is what I changed
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{user:user_name}', // This is what I changed
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});
```

> Still, query result is same: > **select * from `posts` where `uuid` = '@simple' limit 1**

**What I want to achieve**

Let say we visit url: **[www.example.test/@simple](http://www.example.test/@simple)**

> Fetch a user with `user_name` is `@simple` or if the user is not exist, return 404

And also same for with posts

We visit url: **[www.example.test/abcd-1234-efgh-5678](http://www.example.test/abcd-1234-efgh-5678)**

> Fetch a post with `uuid` is `abcd-1234-efgh-5678` or 404 if not exist

Question:

[#1] How to tell Laravel Route: that I have 2 Route groups with different Model Binding? Sorry if this question is kinda confusing, cause my english is not really good

[#2] Have I implement Best practice for route groups and route model binding in Laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What is the result you intend to obtain?
If you are doing what I think you're doing (trying to see what's inside the post), you need to return something like $post->content (replace content with the column you want to get), you may even want to make a view and make the output nicer, plus use a controller for more processing.

As for route model binding, you can refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding), both methods, using table:column and using getRouteKeyName are fine, however, the first one doesn't change the default column, and if you use `{user}` for another route, it will still use the ID column, however, the second one changes the default value, if you use `{user}` for another route, it will use the column you specified.

Also, you should use something like `user/{user:user_name}` and `post/{post:uuid}` instead of just `{user:username}` and `{post:uuid}`, as you have said, it won't know which route you're using. The uri has to be different.

Routes are evaluated in the order you put them, meaning that the second route with `{post:uuid}` will override the route with `{user:username}` since they have the same kind of uri, that is, they both consist of 1 wildcard and nothing else. To solve this, you simply have to make their uri different by adding a static part, for example, add post/ before `{post:uuid}` and/or add user/ before `{user:user_name}` like the example below:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'post/{post:uuid}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'user/{user:user_name}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});
```

**To make it very clear, your 2 routes have the same uri of 1 wildcard and nothing else, thus, the last one that appears with this uri will override all the previous routes with the same uri. Meaning that all the previous routes with this same uri before this will be treated like they don't exist, and when you go to a path with the uri in the format of */[insert something here]*, it fits into the format of having 1 wildcard and it will only go to the last one you specified, that is, the one for posts.**

Since the route for users is declared before the one for posts and they share the same uri, only the one for posts will be used. Even when you are trying to find the user, it still uses the route for posts, if no such "post" with a uuid same as the user_name you provided exists, it will still return an error even when there is indeed such user with such username.

Also, you don't need a route group if there's simply 1 route, though it would be more readable and convenient if you're going to add more routes to the group in the future.

Comment: Hello, I use 2 route group, One for post and the other one is User

So whenever I visit URL like this: `.../@user_name`, it fetch a user

And also, when I visit URl like this: `.../abcd-1234-efgh-5678`, it fetch a post

I knew I can use controller, it just simplifies what I want to tell, the actual code use controllers

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what isn't working right now
Idk if you are simplifying the route's path or what, but the part before {user:user_name} and the part before {post:uuid} cannot be the same.

Comment: `Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'post/{post:uuid}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'user/{user:user_name}',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});` Something like this will do. The pattern must be different or it won’t know which route you’re using

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand your problem, here are the changes you need to make and it will work,
routes/web.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'post/{post:uuid}'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (Post $post) {
        return $post;
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'user/{user:user_name}'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return $user;
    });
});
```

Regular Expression that you use above just does filter the {argument} and check if {argument} is alphanumeric basically, in above both cases it works the same except in user_name it also allows '-'